# How to access Collection Generic Type class

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I have a class like this :

```
public class SubClass <T> extends SuperClass<Collection<T>>{
   public Class<T> getInner() {
      // What goes here?
   }
}
```

Where SuperClass is simply a generic class. My question is how to gain access to a Class object in order to return it? I can't seem to be able to do this because of Type erasure.

Any help?

Comment: It would help if you could go into more detail about what specifically you are trying to do, as your approach may be flawed.

Comment: this dummy class reflects one class in my production that is hard to describe here. I'm convinced what i need to do cannot be done since i have a restriction for no argument constructor. plus i have just noticed a flaw in my design of this class. All the subclasses i want for superclass must not be generic and this is. I will use it as a special case. problem 'solved'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Exactly, type erasure means you have to do it explicitly.

Basically you need `SubClass` to take a `Class<T>` as a parameter in the constructor, and then hang onto it. You can still end up with type erasure issues there though, if `T` is actually meant to be (say) `List<String>`. See [Neal Gafter's blog](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) for more info on this and a workaround, and the [Guice 2.0 `TypeLiteral` class](http://google-guice.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/inject/TypeLiteral.html) for an implementation.

Comment: hmm i was afraid this would be the only option... I need to have this class with no contructor with parameters since it is one of many subclasses of superclass that are created using reflection with a no parameter call to the newInstanse method. So there is absolutely no trick i can use to get around this restriciton? Any ugly hack would help :)

Comment: update to your answer: I will only pass non generic classes to collection<T> so the added type erasure issue will not pop up.